# Set cursor blink rate in URxvt

Tags: terminal, rxvt

I would  like to know if it's possible to change the speed at which the cursor blinks in URxvt. The only blinking-related config option I found was `URxvt.cursorBlink` which is a boolean.

If it's not possible to change the rate in URxvt, I'd like to know what alternative light-weight terminal emulators support such an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it doesn't appear that's configurable.  Look for `cursor_blink_ev` in [`src/Command.C`](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/command.C) and [`src/main.C`](https://github.com/exg/rxvt-unicode/blob/master/src/main.C)

In xterm, the timing is set using the [`cursorOffTime`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:cursorOffTime) and [`cursorOnTime`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:cursorOnTime) resources.

Comment: I was going to write an answer with XTerm too.  (-: